# VS test explorer typescript/jasmine tests in c# project not showing

Tags: c#, typescript, visual-studio, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have solution with some c# libraries containg angular projects.
Problem I am facing is that i cant find typescript tests from that angular projects in test explorer.
In the end i can see only c# tests.

My test explorer have settings like this showing only c# source files...

[image]

Is there possibility to add typescript tests somehow too?
Thanks for any suggestions.
Reason why i need it is to link it to microsoft/azure pdtc items later.